# Вывести содержимое xml из файла в цикле (php)

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли вывести в цикле содержимое xml файла? Чтоб каждый элемент xml файла, выводился. Даже те которые находятся внутри другого тега. При этом не известно, сколько всего содержит внутренних тегов определенные теги.

Вот что я имею ввиду: есть тег `<children>` внутри него находится еще один тег `<sub_children>`, внутри него еще может быть тег. И так множество раз.

Вот такой простой код:

файл: **file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
    <children class-id="1">Text children 1</children>
    <children class-id="2">Text children 2</children>
    <children class-id="3">Text children 3</children>
    <children>
        <sub_children class-name="first">First child</sub_children>
        <sub_children class-name="last">Last child</sub_children>
    </children>
</parent>
```

файл: **index.php**

```
<?php
// создаем элемент
$xml = new DOMDocument();
// подключаем файл с настройками
$xml->load('file.xml');
// привязываем к переменной
$element = $xml->documentElement;
?>
```

Не хочется для каждого элемента делать вот такое дело:

```
$status = $element->getElementsByTagName('sub_children')->item(0);
echo $status->textContent;
```

Хочется динамики, а как это сделать, я без понятия.
И вот еще хотел спросить, возможно ли вывод того, что хранится в атрибутах? Если да, то как это сделать в цикле, динамично?

Спасибо большое за внимание!

Comment: делайте рекурсивную функцию, передавая туда элементы

Comment: @splash58, это каким образом? Мне же не известно имена тегов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с такого:

```
function PrettyPrintXML(DOMNode $xml, $depth=0) {
    foreach ($xml->childNodes as $node) {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $depth) 
            . trim($node->nodeName) 
            . ": " 
            . trim($node->nodeValue) 
            . "\n";

        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            PrettyPrintXML($node, $depth+1);
        }
    }    
}

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('file.xml');

PrettyPrintXML($xml);
```

Comment: тока вот так, наверное, лучше.. или я ошибаюсь? https://eval.in/413906

Comment: спасибо большое, то что нужно!